# Row text moves up when row is deselected in NSOutlineView source list

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

in my app I have set up an NSOutlineView which only displays categories as a sort of menu.
This works just fine but there is a problem when I deselect an item, the titles in each row move up like in the image below:

[image: NSOutlineView deselection problem]

Her is the code I am using:

```
- (NSInteger)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView numberOfChildrenOfItem:(id)item {

    return [sectionsArray  count];
}

- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isItemExpandable:(id)item {

    return NO;
}

-(BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView*)outlineView isGroupItem:(id)item {

    return NO;
}

- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {

    NSTableCellView *cellView = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"DataCell" owner:self];
    cellView.imageView.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"Point.png"];
    cellView.textField.stringValue = item;

    SectionCellCountField *number = [[SectionCellCountField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(cellView.frame.size.width-50, 4, 35, 16)];
    [cellView addSubview:number];

    int rows = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < [dataArray count]; i++) {

        if ([item isEqualToString:[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"Cathegory"]]) {

            rows = rows +1;
        }

    }

    number.stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", rows];

    return cellView;
}

- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView
        child:(NSInteger)index
       ofItem:(id)item {

    return [sectionsArray objectAtIndex:index];

}
```

Anybody have any idea why this is behavior is occurring? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: This doesn't help with your problem, but you could reduce the matching-row-counting code to a one-liner using NSArray's KVC magic and NSCountedSet: `rows = [[NSCountedSet setWithArray:[dataArray valueForKey:@"Cathegory"]] countForObject:item]`

Comment: It's been my experience that Cocoa handling of cell views in aggregate objects can be finicky and unintuitive at times. FWIW, if I was in your shoes I'd set up a bare-bones Cocoa project that replicates the jumping-text issue for others to download, compile and tinker with. That might give some of us (e.g. myself) a better starting point to help out. Just a thought. (Edit: or maybe I'm just being lazy.)

Comment: Are you doing any custom drawing or layout in your cell? It looks like you're using the wrong y-offset. You could also have changed something in IB if you haven't subclassed NSTableCellView. Impossible to tell you what's wrong without access to your xib or subclass. FYI, your cell gets redrawn each time its highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using autolayout? I've seen this sort of thing happen when I forgot to constrain at least two of a table cell view subview's top, bottom, or height. Something about table and outline views tends to make ambiguous layouts act up.